# Enable QMenu access for a disabled QToolButton

Tags: qt, qtgui, qmenu, qaction

I have a `QToolButton` with an attached `QMenu` which includes a couple of `QActions`.
One of those actions is the button's default action. The default action dynamically changes when clicking on the actions and this works great.

Now, these `QActions` get enabled and disabled by signals. When exactly the (current) default action get's disabled, the `QToolButton` gets disabled, too.

This results in an inaccessible `QMenu` which still contains enabled `QMenu` entries (`QActions`) that I want to be able to select.

So: Can I somehow still make the Menu available when the default action is getting a `setEnabled(false)`? Or are there some other Ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did the following to exactly resolve the issue as described:

In my `QToolButton` class I override `eventFilter` as follows:

```
bool MultiToolButton::eventFilter( QObject* inObject, QEvent* inEvent )
{
  MultiToolButton* _multiToolButton = 
    dynamic_cast<MultiToolButton*>(inObject);
  QMouseEvent* _mouseEvent = dynamic_cast<QMouseEvent*>(inEvent); 

  if(_multiToolButton 
    && _mouseEvent && _mouseEvent->type() == QEvent::MouseButtonPress)
  {
    mMenu.setEnabled(true);
    showMenu();
    return true;
  }

  return QToolButton::eventFilter(inObject, inEvent);
}
```

and add the following line to the contructor:

```
installEventFilter(this);
```

Thank you for your answer nonetheless. However, I didn't check it.

Comment: I used a variant of this solution (thanks!).  Is there a way to also paint the menu arrow correctly (enabled instead of disabled)?

Answer (score 0):

Naively what you can do is to write a small function that you call whenever you disable a `QAction` to see if it is the current default action with somethinglike this:

```
void MyDialog::on_button_clicked()
{
  action2->setEnabled( false );
  checkForDefault(action2);
}

void MyDialog::checkForDefault(QAction *action)
{
  if ( tButton->defaultAction() == action ) {
    QList<QAction*> list = tButton->menu()->actions();
    int index = list.indexOf(action);
    QAction *newDefault = list.at( ( index+1 ) % list.count() );
    tButton->setDefaultAction(newDefault);
    tButton->setEnabled(true);
  }
}
```

This will check if the action that was changed is the current default action of the button and if so will select the next `QAction` within the `QMenu` as the new default (or the first action if the disabled action is the last in the list).

A different way would probably be to have your own class inheriting from `QToolButton` and to overload its `actionEvent ( QActionEvent * event )` method to perform what you need.

Is this of any help?

Answer (score 0):

The problem of the arrow being disabled can be solved by the following stylesheet, which replaces the standard arrow with an image located in url `path_to_arrow`. This image does not changed when the button is **disabled** :

```
QToolButton::menu-indicator,::menu-button 
{

}

QToolButton::menu-arrow
{

    image: url("path_to_arrow");

}
```